# Purchased music lost due to lack of space for iOS 7 update?

Tags: iphone, itunes

A few days ago I wanted to upgrade my iOS to version 7, but before I could do this I had to make room by deleting programs that didn't help so much.

So I was forced to delete my music library on my iPhone. And not really thinking about my new purchased music that hasn't been synchronized with iCloud or iTunes. So I lost my new music.

How do I get the music back without buying the music twice? I did a small test by buying one of the songs and Apple charged me again.

Answer (score 5):

On your iOS 7 device:

- Launch iTunes
- Go to the "Other" tab
- Go to Purchased

There you have the songs you bought. You can download them without Apple charging you again.

If Apple charged you again, it's either:

- You bought another version of the song
- You bought it with another iTunes account

Comment: Thank you very much :) I do not have access to my iMac until the 1st of October. I only have my iPhone. I opened iTunes on my iPhone and found 2 purchased songs. In other words I'm still missing about 70 songs.

Comment: It was exactly the same song with the same account! ..but Apple charged me twice

Comment: Does the song show up under the purchased music tab? Do the other 70 songs?

Comment: The free song I got and the one just bought showed up on purchased, not the other 70 missing songs

Comment: Maybe I will have to wait for access to my iMac.